# Ember-Data is generating a route with dots instead of underscores

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember.js, Ember-Data, and the ActiveModelAdapter. One of my models has a two word name, `OfficialRelation`. When Ember-Data tries to post an instance of this model, it uses the url `/official.relations` instead of `official_relations`. I'm not sure if this is intended behavior or not. Either way, I'd like to get url to be `official_relations`.

The route looks like this:

```
Whistlr.OfficialOrganizationsContributeeNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @store.createRecord('officialRelation', {official: @modelFor('official'), type: "Official::Relation::Contributee"})
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('content', model)
  deactivate: ->
    @get('controller.content').rollback()
  renderTemplate: ->
    @render "official/organizations/contributee/new",
      outlet: "contributeeNew"
      into: "official/organizations"
      controller: "officialOrganizationsContributeeNew"
```

UPDATE (model definition)

```
Whistlr.OfficialRelation = DS.Model.extend

  official: DS.belongsTo 'official',
    inverse: 'relations'

  startDate: DS.attr()
  endDate: DS.attr()
  amount: DS.attr()
  description: DS.attr()
```

Comment: Can you add your model definition?

Comment: Added the model definition.